# Expandir un Frame posicionado con "grid()" dentro de otro Frame

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo una aplicación realizada con Python 2.7.x y Tkinter que, entre otras cosas, dispone de la apertura de un widget `Toplevel` a modo de un `Messagebox` personalizado.

Más o menos, el código que sigue es con lo que se construye el Toplevel en cuestión (algunos de los parámetros son mandados desde la ventana principal de la aplicación, tales como la anchura (*w*), altura (*h*), indicador para saber que archivo de idioma importar para mostrar los textos en el idioma adecuado (lng_app), opciones de configuración como colores (_cfg__), etc, ...):

```
# encoding: utf-8


# Tkinter
from libs._import_ import tk, tkFont

_cfg__ = ''
lng = ''


class _tpLvl_MsgBx_(tk.Toplevel):
    '''Ventana secundaria para efectuar la salida del programa.'''

    def __init__(self, parent=None, lng_app=None, _cfg__app=None, _w_='', _h_='', _x_='', _y_='', _tit_app='', _img_logo_app='', msg_type='', msg_txt='', btn_conf_01_txt=None, btn_conf_02_txt=None, extra_design=None, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        global _cfg__, lng
        _cfg__ = _cfg__app
        lng = lng_app

        self.parent = parent
        self._img_logo_app = _img_logo_app
        self.msg_txt = msg_txt
        _w_a_elim_ = 187
        self.msg_box_msg_w = _w_ - _w_a_elim_

        # Fuente por defecto para los Message
        #{'family': 'Arial', 'weight': 'normal', 'slant': 'roman', 'overstrike': 0, 'underline': 0, 'size': 10}   self.mainfont.actual()
        self.font_x_defecto = tkFont.Font(family='Consolas', size=10, weight='bold')

        img_msg_icons = {
            'info': 'img/icon-info.png',
            'confirm': 'img/icon-confirm.png',
            'warning': 'img/icon-warning.png',
            'error': 'img/icon-error.png',
        }

        if(msg_type == 'info'):
            msg_tit = lng.data['msgb_tit_info']
        elif(msg_type == 'confirm'):
            msg_tit = lng.data['msgb_tit_confirm']
        elif(msg_type == 'warning'):
            msg_tit = lng.data['msgb_tit_warning']
        elif(msg_type == 'error'):
            msg_tit = lng.data['msgb_tit_error']
        ####msg_tit += _tit_app
        msg_tit += 'Viajes'
        self.img_msg_icon = tk.PhotoImage(file=img_msg_icons[msg_type])

        self.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(_w_, _h_, _x_, _y_))
        #       lng >> Título del panel según el caso
        self.title(msg_tit)
        self.config(bg=_cfg__._root_color_blanco, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.resizable(1,1)

        self.msg_box_frm_content_main = tk.Frame(self, bg=_cfg__._root_color_quater, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.msg_box_frm_content_main.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        self.msg_box_frm_content = tk.Frame(self.msg_box_frm_content_main, bg=_cfg__._root_color_quater, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.msg_box_frm_content.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.msg_box_frm_btns = tk.Frame(self.msg_box_frm_content_main, bg=_cfg__._root_color_quater, padx=2, pady=5)
        self.msg_box_frm_btns.grid(row=1, column=1)

        if(extra_design is None):

            msg_box_logo = tk.Label(self.msg_box_frm_content_main, image=self._img_logo_app)
            msg_box_logo.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, padx=3)

            msg_box_logo = tk.Label(self.msg_box_frm_content, bg=_cfg__._root_color_quater, image=self.img_msg_icon)
            msg_box_logo.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='n')
            #       lng >> Mensaje a Mostrar
            msg_box_msg = tk.Message(self.msg_box_frm_content, text=self.msg_txt, bg=_cfg__._root_color_quater, padx=10, pady=0)
            msg_box_msg.grid(row=0, column=1)
            msg_box_msg.config(width=self.msg_box_msg_w, anchor='center', font=self.font_x_defecto)

        else:

            if(extra_design == 'info_tot_viajes'):
                ##self.content_info_tot_viajes

                msg_box_logo = tk.Label(self.msg_box_frm_content_main, image=self._img_logo_app)
                msg_box_logo.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, padx=3)

                msg_box_logo = tk.Label(self.msg_box_frm_content, bg=_cfg__._root_color_quater, image=self.img_msg_icon)
                msg_box_logo.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='n')
                #       lng >> Mensaje a Mostrar
                msg_box_msg = tk.Message(self.msg_box_frm_content, text=self.msg_txt['tot_viajes'], bg=_cfg__._root_color_quater, padx=10, pady=0)
                msg_box_msg.grid(row=0, column=1)
                msg_box_msg.config(width=self.msg_box_msg_w, anchor='center', font=self.font_x_defecto)

                msg_box_frm_sub_content = tk.Frame(self.msg_box_frm_content, bg='yellow', bd=2, width=1000)
                msg_box_frm_sub_content.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

                print 'msg_box_frm_sub_content.config() >>', msg_box_frm_sub_content.config()
                print 'self.msg_box_msg_w >>', self.msg_box_msg_w
                self.msg_box_msg_w = 500
                print 'self.msg_box_msg_w >>', self.msg_box_msg_w

                msg_box_bar_tit = tk.Message(msg_box_frm_sub_content, text=self.msg_txt['tot_bar'][0], bg=_cfg__._root_color_quater, padx=5, pady=0)
                msg_box_bar_tit.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
                msg_box_bar_tit.config(width=self.msg_box_msg_w, font=self.font_x_defecto)
                msg_box_bar_tot = tk.Message(msg_box_frm_sub_content, text=self.msg_txt['tot_bar'][1], bg=_cfg__._root_color_quater, padx=5, pady=0)
                msg_box_bar_tot.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='e')
                msg_box_bar_tot.config(width=self.msg_box_msg_w, font=self.font_x_defecto)

                msg_box_hab_tit = tk.Message(msg_box_frm_sub_content, text=self.msg_txt['tot_hab'][0], bg=_cfg__._root_color_quater, padx=5, pady=0)
                msg_box_hab_tit.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')
                msg_box_hab_tit.config(width=self.msg_box_msg_w, font=self.font_x_defecto)
                msg_box_hab_tot = tk.Message(msg_box_frm_sub_content, text=self.msg_txt['tot_hab'][1], bg=_cfg__._root_color_quater, padx=5, pady=0)
                msg_box_hab_tot.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='e')
                msg_box_hab_tot.config(width=self.msg_box_msg_w, font=self.font_x_defecto)

                msg_box_par_tit = tk.Message(msg_box_frm_sub_content, text=self.msg_txt['tot_par'][0], bg=_cfg__._root_color_quater, padx=5, pady=0)
                msg_box_par_tit.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w')
                msg_box_par_tit.config(width=self.msg_box_msg_w, font=self.font_x_defecto)
                msg_box_par_tot = tk.Message(msg_box_frm_sub_content, text=self.msg_txt['tot_par'][1], bg=_cfg__._root_color_quater, padx=5, pady=0)
                msg_box_par_tot.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='e')
                msg_box_par_tot.config(width=self.msg_box_msg_w, font=self.font_x_defecto)

                msg_box_ven_tit = tk.Message(msg_box_frm_sub_content, text=self.msg_txt['tot_ven'][0], bg=_cfg__._root_color_quater, padx=5, pady=0)
                msg_box_ven_tit.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='w')
                msg_box_ven_tit.config(width=self.msg_box_msg_w, font=self.font_x_defecto)
                msg_box_ven_tot = tk.Message(msg_box_frm_sub_content, text=self.msg_txt['tot_ven'][1], bg=_cfg__._root_color_quater, padx=5, pady=0)
                msg_box_ven_tot.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='e')
                msg_box_ven_tot.config(width=self.msg_box_msg_w, font=self.font_x_defecto)

                msg_box_frm_sub_content.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
                msg_box_frm_sub_content.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
                msg_box_frm_sub_content.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
                msg_box_frm_sub_content.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
                msg_box_frm_sub_content.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
                msg_box_frm_sub_content.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)


        if(msg_type == 'info' or msg_type == 'warning' or msg_type == 'error'):

            #       lng >> 'Aceptar'
            msg_box_btn_ok = tk.Button(self.msg_box_frm_btns, text=lng.data['btn_ok'], font=('Consolas', 8), width=5, height=1, command=self.destroy)
            msg_box_btn_ok.grid(row=0, column=0)

        elif(msg_type == 'confirm'):

            if(btn_conf_01_txt is not None and btn_conf_02_txt is not None):
                btn_opc_01_txt = btn_conf_01_txt
                btn_opc_02_txt = btn_conf_02_txt
            else:
                btn_opc_01_txt = lng.data['btn_si']
                btn_opc_02_txt = lng.data['btn_no']

            #       lng >> 'Si' u Opción-01
            msg_box_btn_ok = tk.Button(self.msg_box_frm_btns, text=btn_opc_01_txt, font=('Consolas', 8), width=5, height=1, command=lambda: self.confirm_return(1))
            msg_box_btn_ok.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5)
            #       lng >> 'No' u Opción-02
            msg_box_btn_cncl = tk.Button(self.msg_box_frm_btns, text=btn_opc_02_txt, font=('Consolas', 8), width=5, height=1, command=lambda: self.confirm_return(0))
            msg_box_btn_cncl.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)

    def confirm_return(self, _return):
        '''Devolviendo respuesta de confirmación.'''

        self.parent.confirm_var.set(_return)
        self.destroy()

    def content_info_tot_ent(self):
        '''Contenido personalizado para el panel informativo
        de total de entidades tratadas.'''

        msg_box_logo = tk.Label(self.msg_box_frm_content_main, image=self._img_logo_app)
        msg_box_logo.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, padx=3)

        msg_box_logo = tk.Label(self.msg_box_frm_content, bg=_cfg__._root_color_quater, image=self.img_msg_icon)
        msg_box_logo.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='n')
        #       lng >> Mensaje a Mostrar
        msg_box_msg = tk.Message(self.msg_box_frm_content, text=self.msg_txt, bg=_cfg__._root_color_quater, padx=10, pady=0)
        msg_box_msg.grid(row=0, column=1)
        msg_box_msg.config(width=self.msg_box_msg_w, anchor='center', font=self.font_x_defecto)
```

Este `Toplevel`, como ya he dicho, es una especie de Messagebox personalizado para los típicos mensajes de información, alerta, error y confirmación. Para casos especiales que se salen de un diseño y/o medidas estándar, se indica por el parámetro **`extra_design`**

En el caso que se expone, llega el caso en el que se demanda el `extra_design='info_tot_viajes'`. En dicho caso, existe un `Frame` llamado `msg_box_frm_sub_content` que ocupa una de las celdas del Frame `self.msg_box_frm_content`. El mencionado `msg_box_frm_sub_content` está dividido en dos columnas y cuatro filas.

El problema que tengo es que el Frame `msg_box_frm_sub_content` no llega a expandirse todo lo necesario a lo largo de su celda asignada dentro del `self.msg_box_frm_content`.

Así es como se ve ahora mismo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(he dejado un fondo amarillo en el `msg_box_frm_sub_content` para ver lo que ocupa pero, al final, llevaría el mismo color azul que su Frame padre).

La cosa es que lo que pretendo es que se expanda o en todo lo ancho de la celda que ocupa o, al menos como sale en esta otra imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para que quede más claro la distribución de los Frames (o tablas con sus filas y columnas), ahí va otra imagen ilustrativa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno, pues eso, he tratado varias formas de conseguir que el `msg_box_frm_sub_content` se ensanche pero no lo consigue de ninguna forma.

He tratado de expandir el `Frame` con la propiedad de `grid_rowconfigure()` pero nada.
Incluso, le incremento el ancho, subo y subo de valor pero no cambia nada su tamaño de anchura y se queda igual, le ponga el valor que le ponga.

Entonces, ¿alguien me puede ilustrar dónde tengo el fallo?

---

Por otro lado, aparte del problema de las anchuras y como expandir el Frame adecuadamente, me surgió en el mismo código otra cuestión.

Como se puede ver en el código, dentro del condicional:

```
    if(extra_design is None):

    else:

        if(extra_design == 'info_tot_viajes'):
            ##self.content_info_tot_viajes
```

cuando se cumple el `if(extra_design == 'info_tot_viajes'):`, se llama a `self.content_info_tot_viajes` (ahora está comentado porque no se llega a cargar el contenido del método llamado).
No sé por qué la simple llamada al método no hace que se cargue el contenido construido dentro de él. Debido a que no se llega a cargar he comentado la llamada al método y he puesto el contenido del método dentro del `else`.

¿Por que no basta con la simple llamada al método para que se cargue su contenido dentro del `else`?

Gracias adelantadas por las posibles sugerencias de solución.